# Where in Typescript Generics

Tags: typescript, generics

I have a function that takes an object and a name of a class (which is contained by that object). Getting all the properties of an object isn't hard (`keyof O`), and figuring out if a key is a class isn't hard either (`O[N] extends {new: (..args: any[]) => any}`). However, I cant combine them:

```
function foo<O, N extends keyof O where O[N] extends {new: (...args: any[]) => any}> (obj: O, name: N){}
```

I have seen `Extract<T, U>`, but I can not use `T` inside of the check for `U`. How else would I go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such syntax, you can add a constraint to `O` instead to force the `N` key to have whatever type you need it to have:

```
function foo<O extends Record<N, new (...a: any) => any>, N extends keyof O> (obj: O, name: N){

}

let o = {
    a: class {},
    b: class {},
    c: 0,
}

foo(o, "a") // ok
foo(o, "c") // error
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMOcA8B5RBTAHlbMAEwGdEAlbCOAJyLQDkAaRMbAd0QAoA6PgQwBcifmACeASkQBeAHwjxslgxz5CpRAGtsYuMEQZ5XOACMAVsIwsw-ALbZhDCQG8AUK4C+7gDbYoiOBlEN0RQkWEIb34SMmcPJlcwxBMIqJjg+MSwiGEABgSvVxQ4YxYAIn4yqQB6aoDNItRSxDKIKsRanBoaWiA)